# issuing hard drive commands with java

Tags: java, hard-drive, scsi

Does anyone know of a way to issue commands to a hard drive within Java? Does Java even support this kind of hardware interaction?

For example, if I have a SCSI hard drive that I would like to inquiry, is there a pre-existing Java method to do this, or would I have to write my own?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI has some general information on SCSI commands in case you aren't familiar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java doesn't support talking directly to hardware like that.  However, you can use JNI to call a C/C++ function from Java that can.

Comment: Can I use other languages with JNI to access the hard drive, or is it limited to C/C++?

Alternatively, would it be possible to write a program entirely in C/C++ that is called/run by a Java program?

Comment: Yes and Yes. I've heard you can use aseambly directly, and yes, you can run a complete program from Java.

Answer (score 2):

Three words "JNI or JNA".  I strongly recommend taking a look at the latter to see if it suits your situation, instead of just opting for JNI.

Answer (score 1):

No, since Java runs in a "virtual" machine rather than a real one. But it could be used as a bridge as dj mentioned earlier using JNI.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface#Access_to_assembly_code) JNI can also call assembly directly. JNI could be used to call complete programs written in C or C++

Comment: If the C/C++ code is a complete program, there's no reason to use JNI; you can just execute the program.  JNI is non-trivial to implement, so I wouldn't use it unless I needed to.

JNI is used to call *functions* in other languages.  I used it at Polaroid to talk to a credit card reader.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the HDD interface code in C/C++ and then call that from Java using JNI