# How to read HDD SMART in java

Tags: java

any idea how to do this? I would like to make something like HDTUNE PRO for my course work, but i have no idea how to read HDD Smart in java, is it even possible? Its designed for Windows

Comment: If there are no clases to handle it, you can always switch to JNI and call some native library of your OS

Comment: possible duplicate of [issuing hard drive commands with java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390463/issuing-hard-drive-commands-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some sort of native library in order to do this.

If you're under Linux/Unix, you can probably read the respective entries under `/proc/*` even without a library. But under Windows, I don't think it would be an easy task.

Java is generally not meant for such low-level coding.

Comment: What do you mean by respective entries ? I can't find anything related to SMART in that directory.