# How to collect data about hard disk via Java?

Tags: java, swing

We are using Java coding to make a desktop application but we can not proceed because we fail to collect data about the hard disk drive. More specifically we need to collect data about the state of the hard and send them to the server application.

The code we are using is

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    server = new ServerSocket(9999);
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    System.out.println(err);
                }
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Socket client = server.accept();
                        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                        String line;
                        String l="cnx";
                        String d ="dsk";
                        line = r.readLine();
                        if (  line.equals(l) ){
                            String msg = "";
                            String msgs ="    Paquetsÿ: envoy‚s = 4, re‡us = 0, perdus = 4 (perte 100%),";
                            w.println("Veuillez attendre durant le traitement de votre demande...");
                            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping google.com");
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                            String readline;
                            while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(readline);
                            msg = readline;
                                    }
                            if (msg.equals(msgs)) w.println("Connexion n'est pas établie sur ce PC");
                            else w.println("Connexion établie sur ce PC");

                        }
                        if (  line.equals(d) ){
                            String msg="";
                            w.println("Veuillez attendre durant le traitement de votre demande...");
                            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chkdsk");
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                            String readline;
                            while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(msg);
                            msg += readline +"\n";
                                    }
                            w.println(msg);


                        }
                        client.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            private ServerSocket server;
            });}



    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\stage\\logo.jpg"));
        setTitle("Agent");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please describe the exact problem? What is the question?

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Sockets have *nothing* to do with a question about finding information on the file system of a machine, so should not be included in the code sample.

Comment: If you are looking for thinks like SMART disk status, then this question is a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390463/issuing-hard-drive-commands-with-java

Comment: I need to collect all informations about the hard disk (if it's damaged or not and how much space its left there .....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of data you need? You can collect some data using java.io.File and System both are availabe under JDK. Or else you can use Runtime.exec() to get some other data.

Here is the code for getting the drives that are present::

```
import java.io.File;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File[] drives = File.listRoots();
        if (drives != null && drives.length > 0) {
            for (File aDrive : drives) {
                System.out.println(aDrive);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the link that you can use:::  http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/listing-all-drives-with-type-total-space-and-free-space-in-java